# About cytoscape selectAll, Is there an efficient API?

Tags: cytoscape.js

1. Now, I'm useing cytoscape. And I want select all nodes and edges.
   But I find it's need a long time when the nodes and edges more than
   2000+. Is there an efficient API？
2. I use cytoscape through JavaScript or TypeScript, and I don't use any third-party framework.
3. I'm looking for a solution for JavaScript or TypeScript or a 3rd party framework.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are using RCy3 since you mentioned `selectAll` and an API. If you are using the GUI or Python or something else, please specify.

Using RCy3, there are two relevant functions: `selectAllNodes()` and `select AllEdges()`. Node selection is fast. I selected over 5000 nodes in a fraction of a second. Edge selection, however, can be slow. My sample network has 330,000 edges and this took ~20 seconds to complete.

Looking in the function code, I see it is using the CyREST API call for updating table columns (http://127.0.0.1:1234/v1/swaggerUI/swagger-ui/index.html?url=http://127.0.0.1:1234/v1/swagger.json#!/Tables/updateColumnValues; note: you need to have Cytoscape running to see these Swagger docs). I then tested alternative approaches:

- CyREST API for network edge selection
- CyCommands API for network selection

Both of these ran in ~5 seconds. Significantly faster!

I'll update the implementation code and release it in the next version of RCy3 (due to release by Bioconductor at the end of the month). In the meantime, you can write this raw CyCommands code in R yourself:

```
RCy3::commandsPOST('network select edgeList="all" nodeList="all" network="current"')
```

Thanks for the question!

Comment: Thanks for answering.I didn't describe it clearly, I use cytoscape through JavaScript or TypeScript, and I don't use any third-party framework.

Comment: If you mean cytoscape.js, then you'll want to switch the tag on this issue. That is a completely different piece of software.